# Unable to connect to the Eclipse Mosquitto image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mosquitto

I am unable to reach my Mosquitto server from the client container, and I don't know why.

Here's an extract from the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
   wd_mosquitto:
     image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
     container_name: wd-mosquitto
     ports:
       - 1883:1883

   wd_message_client:
     image: wd_message_client_image
     container_name: wd-message-client
     ports:
       - 1883:1883
     external_links:
       - wd_mosquitto
     depends_on:
       - wd_mosquitto
```

Here's what I get trying to subscribe to the broker from inside the client container `docker exec -it wd-message-client /bin/bash`

```
root@72f57bdda570:/code# mosquitto_sub -h "test.mosquitto.org" -t "#" -C 3
{ replies from the test server that confirm mosquitto_sub works }

root@72f57bdda570:/code# mosquitto_sub -h "tcp://wd-mosquitto:1883" -t "#" -C 3
Unable to connect (Lookup error.).

root@72f57bdda570:/code# ping wd-mosquitto
PING wd-mosquitto (172.19.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.112 ms
```

Good, `mosquitto_sub` works and I can resolve and ping the Mosquitto container, but can't subscribe to the broker.

Here are the results of me fiddling in the Mosquitto container with `docker exec -it wd-mosquitto /bin/sh` (bash isn't available)

```
/ # ps
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 mosquitt   0:00 /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
    6 root       0:00 /bin/sh
   12 root       0:00 ps

/ # mosquitto
1521984736: mosquitto version 1.4.12 (build date 2017-06-01 13:03:46+0000) starting
1521984736: Using default config.
1521984736: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1521984736: Error: Address in use

/ # mosquitto_sub -t "$SYS"
/bin/sh: mosquitto_sub: not found
```

OK, I guess mosquitto_sub isn't included on the docker image, but I can confirm that Mosquitto is running on port 1883. Why isn't it reachable? I haven't specified a config file, so it should allow anonymous connections.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try letting the host ports be randomised?

Comment: What do you mean (i.e. what precise syntax do you propose in the docker-compose.yml file)? And assuming you did expose a random port, what good would that do?

Comment: The port on the container would still be fixed, it's just the port on your local machine that would be randomised, the syntax would be `1883` rather than `1883:1883`

Comment: That worked! Thank you, but I don't understand why yet. Could you please add it as an answer with an explanation so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue with ports

At the moment you map both container ports to the same host port, which may cause some weird issues. As from the container you can talk to any container port directly you do not need to fix the host port too.

## How to fix

You can replace the lines like this:

```
- 1883:1883
```

with:

```
- 1883
```

## Visual

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]